# Windows application for circling, pointing, highlighting and writing comments on a screenshot

Tags: image-editor, screenshot, presentation

Does anyone know of an application that I can use to highlight/circle/comment parts of a screenshot? I sometimes train users, so I need to guide them by showing screenshots of applications. Currently, I'm using MS paint for this but the results are horrendous:

[image]

There are many image editors out there but most focus on enhancing real world pictures. I was hoping that there might be an image editor geared mostly to trainers or that focus on the requirements I've mentioned. These applications are usually called Markup tools, Annotation tools or screenshot editors.

Can anyone suggest a simple to use app that will do what I need? The app should work in Windows. It doesn't have to be free, it just needs to be non-complex & produce quality visually appealing results.

Comment: You could import the picture into PowerPoint, add all the custom symbols and words you need, then export it back to a picture

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Would you add your system requirements? (Windows, low Memory footprint... whatever it is you need) Also please explain why just any random image editor won't do it. As it stands your question is very broad. Please do try to narrow it down.

Comment: It would be nice if you could be a bit more specific.

Comment: *Should* or *must* work on Windows? Is a Web application okay?

Comment: Similar question for Linux: [Simple program to edit screenshots (add texts and arrows, mark stuff)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3069/60)

Comment: Also consider [GrabNDrop](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/163/tool-for-taking-screenshot-and-quickly-editing-it/25130#25130).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/). You can take screenshots in various ways (whole desktop, one window, selection etc.), save, mail, print or edit it and highlight parts, add text and arrows, and more.
[image]

Comment: This really is a great app. And its fully free also. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: For my purposes I can truly say this app did it for me. Absolutely free, no hidden toolbars. Been using it for a couple of says and loving it. Skitch is great too for more colorful visuals. Using both together you get everything you could want. Can't believe I used MS paint for so long.

Comment: It's also open-source under GPLv3.

Comment: A slight downside is, it has no scaling. So, it's hard to edit images larger than the screen like photos.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a great app. Because it captures mouse pointer every time. Very annoying, sorry.

Comment: @AlexHerman You can disable that. It's even in the first menu item in the Quick settings (or whatever it's called in English).

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Skitch](http://evernote.com/skitch/):

- free
- works with Windows/Mac (even Android/iPhone)
- circle/comment/arrow/check/etc parts of an image
- can take screenshots and crop+edit on the fly
- it does not allow highlighting, but the latter is really not obvious to find (requires OCR).

---

I added 2 annotations on this image with Skitch, I find thempretty smooth:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use PowerPoint for this all the time to set up training guides.  Just take screenshots of some program then use call outs and auto shapes to highlight what is important.  You can format the shapes color/line width things like that.  It is definitely not a true document markup tool but it certainly does the trick and being that it is software most anyone has it does the trick.

Your image with some auto shapes added...nothing fancy

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion James. I was looking for something more visually appealing to engage the users but I might have to end up the PowerPoint option.

Comment: It's definitely a more manual/user intensive option than a program specifically designed to do what you are looking for, but if you add animations to the objects you can throw in a little flair as well.  Its a good stand-by if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I found an application called [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html). Its a commercial app but they offer a free trial version. It seems to have everything I need, so this is the one I'll be using.

I also found SnapDraw which is freeware. But pay attention during installation because it will ask you to install a conduit browser toolbar which is almost impossible to get rid of.

Comment: SnagIt 7.2.5 is officially freeware. I recommend it. It can be found on internet including registration key (which was given against filling registration form that time - but the same key was given to everyone).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm):

- non-free (20 USD)
- works with Windows 98, ME, XP, Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8
- highlight/circle/comment/arrow/check/etc parts of an image. Also allows resizing, cropping, sharpening, watermarking, applying edge effects, and so on.
- can take screenshots and crop+edit on the fly

[image]