# Simple program to edit screenshots (add texts and arrows, mark stuff) on Linux

Tags: linux, gratis, ubuntu, image-editor, screenshot

I have quite often the need to take screenshots and do the following:

- Crop them
- Add texts (where I want to be able to choose the color)
- Add arrows (where I want to be able to choose the color)
- Mark stuff with rectangles / ellipses (where I want to be able to choose the color)
- Free-hand draw

Is something like this available for Linux Mint (which is Ubuntu based)?

I know I can do this with GIMP, but drawing arrows with GIMP is a pain. Also, GIMP has much more functions than I need.

[Awesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce/related) is quite nice for taking screenshots in Chrome, but sometimes I also need to take screenshots outside of the browser.

Comment: Duplicate of [Tool to add shapes, annotations and text using templates to images](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3578/tool-to-add-shapes-annotations-and-text-using-templates-to-images)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My first thought was "ok you need something like [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org)" so, after some search, I found [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) which offers the features you need (more info in this [blog post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/linux-screenshot-program-tool/)).
 You can download it from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/shutter). More details:

- Capture options like capture a specific area or whole desktop
- Share options like generating shared link and Ubuntu One(which has stopped I think)
- Edit options like these screenshots:
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Do you have plugins installed? I don't see any possiblity to edit screenshots with shutter (except from cropping).

Comment: @moose: The left sidebar (as shown in the screenshots) contains all editing tools (including cropping): freehand, marker, lines, arrows, etc. You can switch to the edit mode via a toolbar button (in the top right).

Comment: @unor for a matter of seconds :), isn't the edit button in the top right bringing the shutter drawing tool up front?

Comment: @dimzak I had to install `libgoo-canvas-perl`. You should probably add this to your answer. Without this package, you can't edit. That was the problem I had. (Besides this: Great answer :-) Shutter is very nice :-) )

Comment: Relevant blog post re. `libgoo-canvas-perl`: http://shutter-project.org/2010/05/how-to-reanimate-disabled-features/

Comment: I use shutter almost daily, it's really awesome!

Comment: Shutter is great but it is no longer under active development and faces some very annoying bugs. Example: [font settings not being preserved](http://i.imgur.com/Cwyssli.gif)

Comment: is it that easy to draw arrows in  Gimp?

Answer (score 22):

## [Flameshot](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot)

[image: 1]

Super easy to use. I mapped it to my `PrtSc`.

Comment: I just tried it. This app is awesome - and in the official package sources!

Comment: it's great although it's currently missing to add a textbox

Comment: I started to use shutter. Flameshot was not able to open for me (ubuntu 20) and for many other users for some reason, issue is still open: https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot/issues/90

Comment: Also great on Archlinux.

Comment: I've been using flameshot for years, but now i found that both shutter and flameshot are useless under wayland

Comment: @zkvarz I needed to start it from the command line: `flameshot gui`, then it worked just perfect

Comment: @ice Flameshot works with Wayland. If you are referring to the regrettable "share" prompt for screenshot on Gnome / Wayland that shipped in Jammy, that is Gnome problem, not Flameshot (see https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/649, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4895).

Answer (score 7):

## [HotShots](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hotshots/support?source=navbar)

Hotshots is a screenshot tool with some editing features. It is particularly suitable for writing documentation, but you can use it to highlight some details on a map image or what ever you want.

## Features

Some important features:

- Free/libre software and *gratis*
- Can take screenshots: all screens, full screen, window, region, free hand region
- Can crop those screenshots or any image inside its editor
- Can add texts (where you will be able to choose the color)
- Can add arrows (where you will  be able to choose the color)
- Can mark stuff with rectangles / ellipses/ polygons/ curves (where you will be able to choose the color)
- Can use “system” shortcuts to take a screenshot.

## Platform support

- Linux (needs compilation such as on Slackware Linux; [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hotshots/files/)) -- `libXfixes` and `libqxt` would be needed before compilation. Also, developer says that compiled packages are also available for Ubuntu and Arch Linux.
- Windows XP/Vista/7/8

## Usage

HotShots is pretty simple to use (similar to **KolourPaint**, **MS Paint** or **GIMP**, if you used any of them). I have put some of the asked features in a screenshot.

In the following screenshot, you would find:

- the interface of the HotShots
- zoom in on "Soft"
- custom text written below website's title
- a red colored arrow pointing to **Questions**
- a rectangle bordering first line of your question's body
- an image of a turtle added where question's stats were visible
- blurred the fourth requirement of your question's body
- made a free curve to make up for free hand requirement accompanied by a text box below it
- highlighted with yellow color a line of the body
- enclosed "Love this site?" by an ellipse
- encircled kittens roaming on my desktop

[image: IMG: HotShots features]

Comment: links not valid. except one for download on sourceforge

Comment: @Zam thank you for bringing this to my notice. I have removed them as such.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest **Libreoffice Draw** (and **Dia**) be added to dimzak's handy recommandation.

*Draw* allows to insert vector based signs such as arrows, ellipses, block arrows or numbers, very easily.
Being vector-based, signs can be moved and resized in a breeze. IMHO they look more 'professionnal' than pixel-based ones like in Shutter and GIMP.

References

- Lists Draw's available signs: https://help.libreoffice.org/Sdraw/.uno:Ellipse
- [How to create custom arrows for LO Draw](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/858/how-to-create-custom-arrows-for-lo-draw/)

Comment: The problem with Draw is that it forces your screenshot in a page layout and you can’t conveniently edit your 1920x1080 image.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later, I recommend Deepin Screenshot (*deepin-screenshot*). Deepin Screenshot takes screenshots, allows annotations and is very handy to use.

It's the best advanced screenshot tool for me (under Xubuntu => available in the official repositories).

The project webpage is here: https://cr.deepin.io/#/admin/projects/deepin-screenshot

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1033231/10425

Comment: And unfortunately, [no longer supported](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-screenshot), with a note that it has been "[migrated into `deepin-screen-recorder`](https://www.deepin.org/en/original/deepin-screen-recorder/)".

Answer (score 1):

## Yet another choice: Drawings

https://maoschanz.github.io/drawing/

- Arrows
- Shapes
- Texts
- ...

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted. This is definitely the app I was looking for, simple, lightweight, fits on my screenshot workflow, and as a bonus it's a GNOME Circle app.

Answer (score 0):

I really <s>like</s> liked **[Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/)**. Its feature set is surprisingly robust for such a small application.

> Pinta is a free, open source drawing/editing program modeled after Paint.NET. Its goal is to provide users with a simple yet powerful way to draw and manipulate images on Linux, Mac, Windows, and *BSD.
>
> [image: Pinta's User Interface]

Comment: Pinta is terrible at annotations. Try moving some text you've added.

Comment: That's pretty good spelling for a dog:)

Comment: @DanDascalescu use the layers!

Comment: I have a love/hate relationship with Pinta - it regularly crashes on Ubuntu 18.04. Installed with this instructions - https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Pinta/

Comment: @MadMike I have to agree. It's been horrible this last year or so. I've started using gThumb.

Comment: I'm here cause I just uninstalled pinta. It was good, but now it's an unstable pos. Krita is pretty easy, Gimp is good for some thing but simple things are a pita.