# Good screenshot annotation tools on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screenshot, annotation

**UPDATE:** @Jan Doggen, **please spend some time actually read my question** and try to understand it instead of bashing it. You first thought "*the answers suggested there do not meet my criteria*" was already wrong, because what I was saying is that **you can't find anything from suggested answer there**, as all the answers are blank page now.

You then point out that it is possible duplicate, but PLEASE read my question again, **your "new finding" is actually the first thing that I put in my OP**. And I made it clear that "The previous one is not providing the answer". **For anyone starting to pick a good screenshot annotation tools, is it a good idea to use the stalled information and force them to use the defunct and un-maintained tool if there are newer and better tools out there?**

I appreciate your enthusiasm, but greater privilege comes with greater responsibility. Please excise them with care.

**Original OP:**

As there hasn't been a good screenshot annotation tools on Linux, preferable GTK based, I'm putting the question here, as the previous one, [Simple program to edit screenshots (add texts and arrows, mark stuff) on Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/simple-program-to-edit-screenshots-add-texts-and-arrows-mark-stuff-on-linux), it's answer/solution has gone defunct. None of the given links gives me anything now:

http://shutter-project.org/
http://shutter-project.org/2010/05/how-to-reanimate-disabled-features/

OK, back to the question, mainly a summary from [the reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/27jd81/what_are_some_good_screenshot_annotation_tools_on/),

Basically, I'm looking for something like [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) (open source but Windows only tool). You just can capture region, last-region, it has window detection, built in editor with easy to set-up-and-edit-later-arrows, obfuscation, cropping, text etc. It's time saver and it's really nice tool.

As for all tools I tested,

- Gimp is out of the question because it requires quite a lot of kung-fu for basic stuff. See [the reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/27jd81/what_are_some_good_screenshot_annotation_tools_on/) for details.
- [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) is defunct and out of maintenance. Moreover, it has "too much Ubuntu cruft"
- Gpaint, the Paintbrush clone for GNOME, lacks the fundamental undo/redo option, which make it practically useless.
- mtpaint is just anther Paintbrush clone that can't foot the required bill easily
- imagemagick can do only very basic annotation but can't support drawing the box, arrow, or circle.
- Also, neither the following archlinux wiki links have the tools that I'm looking for,

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Graphics_and_image_manipulation
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Taking_a_screenshot#Dedicated_software

Comment: *it's answer/solution has gone defunct*?? Are you saying that all the answers suggested there do not meet your criteria? In that case, this does not merit opening a new question and the one should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I thought I was quite clear. Maybe you need to open it up and check?  The answer/solution it gave points to http://shutter-project.org/, and that has gone defunct. Can you make anything out from that answer? Can you still see the blog http://shutter-project.org/2010/05/how-to-reanimate-disabled-features/? Can you download anything from there? Clearer this time?

Comment: *If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by offering a bounty on any question more than two days old.* (quoted from [our help center on "What should I do if no one answers my question?"](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)). Hint: Editing the question – e.g. giving more details – brings it back to the front-page (on the "activity" tab), and thus also attracts potential answerers. // Btw: Shutter still does fine for me, and didn't disappear from the repo :)

Comment: @xpt try: https://launchpad.net/shutter - most recent release was less than 6 months ago.

Comment: thanks, but I'd rather avoid investing my time on such dead-end product to begin with. The home page is gone says a lot about the future of that product.