# super lightweight screen capture utility

Tags: windows, screenshot

I need a very simple screen capture program to create lots of screenshots.

All I need is:

- press a key combination such as ALT-PRT
- screenshot is saved somewhere as a png file with a generated file name

That's it. I don't want any extra image editing functions, not even a dialog for the file name.

The DropBox screenshot feature is exactly what I need however I can't install DropBox on the PC due to security concerns. All other tools I have found so far are not free, too big, install ad ware or require extra steps after the screen capture.

Please advise.

Comment: Also consider [GrabNDrop](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/25130/18184)

Answer (score 2):

### Windows 8

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>.

The full screen screenshots are saved in `Pictures/Screenshots` in your user folder.

Comment: Will this also work for Windows 7? My keyboard does not have the Win key, is this configurable?

Comment: @nn4l No, this is a Windows 8-only feature.

Answer (score 1):

### [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)

- It should support Windows 7, but I can't find any reference on its website at the moment.
- You can configure the keyboard shortcut. The default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>
- It saves the screenshot in a pre-configured format and directory.

You have configure the auto-saving for it to work according to your requirements:

(I'm sorry that the screenshots are in German. I couldn't find a language option in Greenshot.)

[image][image]

Comment: Take me as reference. Using it on Win7 at work, and used it at the very same PC with Vista even :) There's also a portable version available (which is what I currently use).