# Windows software that allows screenshot, crop and share to be done in few clicks

Tags: windows-7, images, copy-paste

A lot of text books that I own are in the PDF format. Since PDF doesn't really draw well in Kindle, I follow this procedure

```
PDF -> word (via manual copy pasting) -> Mobi
```

to convert them to Mobi format for seamless reading.

I come across a lot of images in these PDFs and I use the traditional way of copying images

```
CTRL + Prt Scr -> Paste in Paint -> Crop -> Copy -> Paste in docx
```

which tends to be very cumbersome.

I am looking for a software that would require only a few clicks (or button combinations) to do **capture -> crop -> copy -> paste of the images**.

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDF directly in Word? This is possible since Word 2013 and might give reasonable output for your PDF.

Comment: I found the answer to this question on: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/163/tool-for-taking-screenshot-and-quickly-editing-it/ .. .. so it can be marked duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

A program that may meet your requirements is called [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html). It allows specific configurations to be created, allowing for nearly automatic capture and save of screen shots.

The hot-key is PrintScreen by default but can be changed to anything you wish. The workflow, based on your example, might be to configure a specific window area for capture, which covers the crop aspect. Additionally, automatic file naming and folder save is available. You would have a dedicated folder to accept the files, named, for example, Document0000 or just anything at all.

Once you've completed the captures, the folder would have a file for each screen shot, which you could then import to your document.

You did not specify a free program, and the full version costs US$49.95, which is a reasonable price for such flexibility and power. You may find additional features to be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I did a few more searches on software recommendations to find Greenshot and Windows Snipping tool. I am going with Greenshot. :)

Comment: The price for Greenshot is a good aspect, isn't it? Glad you found something that works. From my understanding of SE, you'll want to post your solution as an answer, then accept it, otherwise in weeks ahead, this will resurface as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Would [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) help with converting to `.mobi` ?